# How to merge uncommon changes in a file on which multiple users are working using git's plugin of Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: eclipse, excel, git

1. I have an excel file on which multiple users are working .
2. As a result two seperate files are being created with same name
   (with a set of different data) on their local systems.
3. I want to merge these two files into one file which has common data + the uncommon changes made by the multiple users.
4. I am using git to handle the project. Solution for the above will
   help each of the users to pull/commit the latest updated file.
5. I have found git merge-file  
    command over stackflow , tried but it is overiding
   the complete set of current-version with other-version.

Comment: git can't merge excel files. It would need to know the file format, and the application logic involved.

Comment: Its a selenium framework and I am using excel file to perform read and write operations . Every time a user performs write operation ,it changes. We have a requirement that before committing the new file version , we perform a merge operation with the original one so that new changes are also included with the existing ones.